# Get current URL in Form action

Tags: wp-admin, forms

I am developing a Form in Admin Panel. My Form code is like below

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));?>" name="newAddress" id="createuser" class="validate" novalidate="novalidate">
```

My Current URL is like below

```
http://localhost/wordpress123/wp-admin/admin.php?page=newAddress
```

I need below code in Form

```
<form method="post" action="/wordpress123/wp-admin/admin.php?page=newAddress" name="newAddress" id="createuser" class="validate" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Comment: Forms submit to the current URL by default. Just leave the action parameter out if you want it to be the current URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` instead of `home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));`

Comment: Keep in mind that `$_SERVER` values are unsafe and you at least should escape them with `htmlspecialchars`. Empty `action=""` would be safer option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585525/risk-of-using-serverrequest-uri-or-serverphp-self-in-forms-and-links

Answer (score -1):

Forms submit to the current URL by default. Just leave the action parameter out if you want it to be the current URL.

```
<form method="post" name="newAddress" id="createuser" class="validate" novalidate="novalidate">
```